# Interrupting grails dynamic methods

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-validation

I have one grails application.In that I have one model class named Book.
From any controller if I am calling Book.list(), Book.get(id) and some other hibernate calls like save() I want to authorize using current login user role.
If authorization fails i have to throw some error.
Is there any plugin available for this.
Please give me some idea or suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the following interceptors in domain classes.Using this we can handle easily

```
 def onLoad={

    }

  def beforeInsert={

  }

   def beforeDelete={

  }

   def beforeUpdate={

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

take a look at: http://www.grails.org/Controllers+-+Interceptors